# PHP inside echo HTML

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am a little bit confused about how to change this `span class="core"` in the code below

```
<?php 
if( ! defined( 'CP_VC_ACTIVE' ) ) {
echo '<li><span class="core">'.esc_html__('Required','cpo').'</span><a target="_blank" href="'. esc_url( admin_url( 'themes.php?page=tgmpa-install-plugins' ) ) . '"> '. esc_html__('hi iam here', 'cpo') . '</a></li>'; 
}
?>
```

to this `span class="<?= $styles['core']; ?>"`

Answer (score 1):

Just close PHP tag and write HTML codes:

```
<?php
if( !defined( 'CP_VC_ACTIVE' ) ){
   ?>
   <li>
      <span class="<?php echo $styles['core']; ?>"><?php echo esc_html__('Required','cpo')?></span>
      <a target="_blank" href="<?php echo esc_url(...); ?>"><?php echo esc_html__('hi I am here', 'cpo'); ?></a>
   </li>
   <?php
}
?>
```

But if you want to keep your code, this is how you can do it:

```
echo '<li><span class="' .$styles["core"] . '">'.esc_html__('Required','cpo').'</span><a target="_blank" href="'. esc_url( admin_url( 'themes.php?page=tgmpa-install-plugins' ) ) . '"> '. esc_html__('hi iam here', 'cpo') . '</a></li>';
```